# how to change the css of a div with javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I made a div with jquery, and after that div is made i want to change the css of it. However, the change doesn't work.

This is my HTML:

```
<form>
        <input type="text" id="color" placeholder="color"><br>
        <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="height"><br>
        <input type="text" id="width" placeholder="width"><br>
        <input type="button" id="make" value="Make">
    </form>
```

and this is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#make').click(function() {
                if (($('#color').val().length) == 0 || ($('#height').val().length) == 0 || ($('#width').val().length) == 0 ) {
                    alert('lol')
                } else {
                    var color = $('#color').val();
                    var height = $('#width').val();
                    var width = $('#height').val();
                    $('body').append('<div id="kast" style="background:'+color+'; width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px;"></div>')
                    $('#make').remove();
                    $('form').append('<input type="button" id="change" value="Change">');

                }
            })
            $('#change').click(function() {

                var color = $('#color').val();
                var height = $('#width').val();
                var width = $('#height').val();
                $('#kast').css('background-color', color);
            })
        })
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: The element is not in the code when the page loads. you first have to enter the color and the dimensions. then you can click on make. After you've made the div #kast then the button change appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'on' as you are creating it dynamically : [on](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
 $('body').on('click','#change',function() {
       var color = $('#color').val();
       var height = $('#width').val();
       var width = $('#height').val();
       $('#kast').css('background-color', color);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic elements

```
$('form').on('click', '#change', function() {
    var color = $('#color').val();
    var height = $('#width').val();
    var width = $('#height').val();
    $('#kast').css('background-color', color);
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GwP5/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `click()` with event delegate:

```
$(document).on('click, '#change', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in this situation that you can't just use as `$('#change').click` to bind a event on a DOM object which you created after the page was already loaded. You should use these below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#change', function() {

          var color = $('#color').val();
          var height = $('#width').val();
          var width = $('#height').val();
          $('#kast').css('background-color', color);

      });
```